# Deno: unable to import a library which contains relative imports

Tags: import, rdf, deno

I'm trying to write some code that uses [Deno](https://deno.land) and [rdflib](https://github.com/rdflib). And failing miserably.

Here's my test program:

```js
// @deno-types="https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts"
import { Namespace } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index'
```

when I ask deno to cache the remote packages, it fails:

```shell
$ deno --unstable cache rdflib.ts
Check file:///home/ian/projects/personal/deno-experiments/rdflib.ts
error: TS2502 [ERROR]: 'thisArg' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
    bind<T>(this: T, thisArg: ThisParameterType<T>): OmitThisParameter<T>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    at asset:///lib.es5.d.ts:350:22

TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/query"' has no exported member 'Query'. Did you mean to use 'import Query from "https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/query"' instead?
import { Query } from './query';
         ~~~~~
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts:16:10

TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/updates-via"' has no exported member 'UpdatesSocket'. Did you mean to use 'import UpdatesSocket from "https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/updates-via"' instead?
import { UpdatesSocket } from './updates-via';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts:26:10

TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/updates-via"' has no exported member 'UpdatesVia'. Did you mean to use 'import UpdatesVia from "https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/updates-via"' instead?
import { UpdatesVia } from './updates-via';
         ~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts:27:10

TS2749 [ERROR]: 'Store' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Store'?
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts:32:32

... many more lines ...

TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/utils/termValue"' has no exported member 'termValue'. Did you mean to use 'import termValue from "https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/utils/termValue"' instead?
export { termValue } from './utils/termValue';
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://dev.jspm.io/npm:rdflib@2.2.7/lib/index.d.ts:40:10

Found 44 errors.
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is with lines in the remote code that do relative imports. Do such relative imports not work with Deno, or am I missing some vital step, or is my approach doomed?

Version info:

```shell
$ deno --version
deno 1.12.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 9.2.230.14
typescript 4.3.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that they are relative specifiers, but that they are not fully qualified. From section 6.6 in the manual:

> ### [Can I use TypeScript not written for Deno?](https://deno.land/manual@v1.12.2/typescript/faqs#can-i-use-typescript-not-written-for-deno)
>
> Maybe. That is the best answer, we are afraid. For lots of reasons, Deno has chosen to have fully qualified module specifiers. In part this is because it treats TypeScript as a first class language. Also, Deno uses explicit module resolution, with no *magic*. This is effectively the same way browsers themselves work, though they don't obviously support TypeScript directly. If the TypeScript modules use imports that don't have these design decisions in mind, they may not work under Deno.
>
> Also, in recent versions of Deno (starting with 1.5), we have started to use a Rust library to do transformations of TypeScript to JavaScript in certain scenarios. Because of this, there are certain situations in TypeScript where type information is required, and therefore those are not supported under Deno. If you are using `tsc` as stand-alone, the setting to use is `"isolatedModules"` and setting it to `true` to help ensure that your code can be properly handled by Deno.
>
> One of the ways to deal with the extension and the lack of Node.js non-standard resolution logic is to use [import maps](https://deno.land/manual@v1.12.2/linking_to_external_code/import_maps) which would allow you to specify "packages" of bare specifiers which then Deno could resolve and load.